# IPython notebook in zc.buildout not using eggs path

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've build an environment with zc.buildout including IPython script.

My problem is simple:

- if I launch IPython in console, everything is OK and I get all my eggs in sys.path
- but if I launch IPython notebook, I only get default system path.

Is there any way to include all my eggs while starting notebook?

Regards,

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

So, I guess somewhere in the notebook startup a process is forked, which means sys.path will get reset and buildout's tricks won't help.

I solved the problems as follows, although it's a bit dirty:

1. Create an entry point as follows:

   ```
   setup(...
         entry_points = {
             'console_scripts': ['ipython = <yourpackage>.ipython:main']
         })
   ```
2. Put the following in /ipython.py:

   ```
   from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance
   import os
   import sys

   def main():
       os.environ['PYTHONPATH']=':'.join(sys.path)
       sys.exit(launch_new_instance())
   ```

Now, running `bin/ipython notebook` will give you the sys.path you expect.