# IPython notebook kernel dies within a zc.buildout setup

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython, jupyter-notebook, buildout

I use zc.buildout to build my python application environment. I want to run IPython notebook and use my custom packages to further test and develop.

```
[buildout]
extends = buildout.cfg

parts += 
    ipython_part

[versions]
ipython = 0.13.2
pyzmq = 13.0.2


[ipython_part]
#http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html#dependencies-for-the-ipython-html-notebook
#https://github.com/bearstech/ipython_notebook/blob/master/buildout.cfg
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
dependent-scripts = true
eggs = 
       ipython[zmq,notebook,test]
       ${myapplication:eggs}
```

Starting the notebook works, but as soon as I create a new notebook the Kernel dies.

```
[NotebookApp] Kernel started: c7c64caf-c966-4863-b37d-11cf11901882
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named IPython.zmq.ipkernel
```

Running IPython inside a virtualenv works like a charm. My problem is related to a buildout setup. I am aware of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621896/ipython-notebook-in-zc-buildout-not-using-eggs-path). It works.

Regarding the wide spread use of buildout & IPython notebook this must be a common situation. Are there any buildout recipes to make it work out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873939/2948099) in the notebook startup a process is forked and looses the sys.path prepared by buildout. The same solution should apply to your case as well.

**Edit**: I settled on adding an initialization keyword to my "development" recipe:

```
[development]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ipython[all]
# ugly work-around needed for ipython nootbook
initialization =
    import sys, os
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = ':'.join(sys.path)
```

Much more clean and it mostly work.

Comment: Thanks for answering my rather old question. Did you notice that in my question I am already referring to the answer you recommend?

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness, I updated the answer with the work-around I use now.

Comment: Awesome. I knew it could be done just with the power buildout offers. Thank you.